# Sequentially highlighting divs using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create kind of runway of lights and here's what it looks like now

http://jsfiddle.net/7NQvq/

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var index = 0;

setInterval(function(){
    if(index > divs.length+20){
        index = 0;
    }
    if(divs[index-1]){
        divs[index-1].className = '';
    }
    if(divs[index]){
        divs[index].className = 'active';
    }

    index++;
}, 50);
```

What I don't like about it is that it's completely inflexible and hard to adjust. Furthermore it also runs additional 20 empty cycles which is wrong. Is there a better way to achieve it (preferrably pure JS)?
It seemes that there must be some combination of setInterval and setTimeout but I just can't make it work.

Comment: What do you mean it runs an additional 20 cycles?

Comment: if(index > divs.length+20)
Here it doesn't do anything useful between divs.length and divs.length+20. Basically it's 20*50ms delay between two turns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
function cycle(selector, cssClass, interval) {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector),
        prev = elems[0],
        index = 0,
        cssClassRe = new RegExp("\\s*\\b" + cssClass + "\\b");

    if (elems.length === 0) return;

    return setInterval(function () {
        if (prev) prev.className = prev.className.replace(cssClassRe, "");
        index %= elems.length;
        elems[index].className += " " + cssClass;
        prev = elems[index++];
    }, interval);
}
```

and

```
var runwayIntval = cycle("div", "active", 100);
```

and at some point

```
clearInterval(runwayIntval);
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/arNY8/1/

---

Of course you could argue that toggling a CSS class is a little limited. You could work with two callback functions instead: one to switch on a freely definable effect, one to switch it off:

```
function cycle(elems, enable, disable, interval) {
    var prev = elems[0], index = 0;

    if (elems.length === 0) return;

    return setInterval(function () {
        index %= elems.length;
        if (prev) disable.call(prev);
        enable.call(elems[index]);
        prev = elems[index++];
    }, interval);
}
```

and

```
var cycleIntval = cycle(
    document.querySelectorAll("div"), 
    function () { 
        this.className += " active";
    },
    function () { 
        this.className = this.className.replace(/\s*\bactive\b/, "");
    },
    100
);
```

Comment: Toggling class is no problem, the point where I stuck is that moment when the last div fades and the first div should wait for, say, 1sec before running another round.

Comment: But when stuff is done in an interval loop, like above, there is no "last" or "first". Why would the "last" element behave any different than the others?

Comment: Exacty! And that's the problem. =) Like you said, the interval should be cleared at some moment(after the last element fades) and in 1 second set again. Or, at least that's what I see as possible solution. But when trying to implement it I fall into either chaotic intervals overlap or eternal loop etc.

Comment: Instead of disabling/enabling the entire interval: Use a Boolean flag that determines whether the interval body is executed or not. Now when you are at the last element, set the flag together with a `setTimeout()` that clears it after a second or so. That way the orignial interval keeps running, but it does nothing until the flag is cleared again.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some adjustments to use a CSS `animation` rather than messing around with transitions and class toggling.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NQvq/1/)

All the JavaScript does now is define the animation delay for each dot.

You can adjust:

- The animation delay - I just have `i/10`, but you could make it `i/5`, `i/20`... experiment!
- The animation duration - it's set to `1s` in my Fiddle, but try shorter and longer to see what happens
- The `50%` that indicates when the light has faded out

Comment: It doesn't run. Missing vendor prefixes I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I usually can't be bothered with those XD But you can add them in easily enough if you need them.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean.
  Here's the version fixed for webkit - [http://jsfiddle.net/7NQvq/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/7NQvq/2/)

But in this case the problem is that it runs first to last divs almost instantly and then slowly fades, while what I want is to highlight them one by one. But anyway, thanks!